# LWP::UserAgent post method not return value

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

Just copy this code from perl cook book 2nd ed pp. 796

it returns:
400 URL must be absolute.

What's wrong with this code?

```
#!"c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -w

use 5.006;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $resp = $ua->post("www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/search-handle-form",
                     { "url"             => "index-books",
                       "field-keywords"  => "perl"}
);
my $content = $resp->content;

print $content, "\n";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the `http://` on the front of the URL

Well, presumably `http://`, it might be `https://`, `ftp://`, etc, etc.